# How can I block clicks and Java Script in a HTML <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML div with or withouth embeded content, I want to block right and left click. 
So if the user clicks or right clicks nothing happens.

Can you do that with HTML/CSS/ Java Script ?

Basicly this is a question about breaking the rules, say you have an youtube embeded video in a div in html, how do you block the click from the user so that if he clicks the video he does not go to youtube dot com.

*note, i am not interested in youtube only, i just want a way to block clicks and right clicks in a div.

So take a much simple scenario:

In a basic HTML page, there is a div with absolute position and size, If the user clicks a link in that div I want it not to work, but if he clicks a link anywhere else on a page I want it to work.

Comment: @DCoder hmz... how do I do that ?

Comment: Of course you can, with JavaScript.
>Why aren't you publishing an answer, so?
Accept more anwers before.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  It will confuse your users.

Comment: You can use javascript to catch the click event in a DOM node, but any user can disable javascript and click as much as they like.

Comment: Ok, now I get what you mean, but there is no answer that comepletely answers my question, there was a coment about an overlay div... but it disappeared.

Comment: @FlaviusFrantz, you have 4 other questions to which you have not accepted answers.  Your help will be of lower quality if you do not put effort into your questions.

Comment: I've reasked the question here with sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543406/how-to-block-click-right-cliks-links-and-posibly-java-script-in-a-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do ignore the clicks is using css 'pointer-events'.

For instance:

```
div.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
```

OR

```
<div id="content" style="pointer-events:none;">
```

Comment: This will disable all mouse events to that div

Answer (score 1):

Use an overlay with a bigger DIV or use the following code

```
var event = $(document).click(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
return false;
```

});

Comment: I want just for one div, not the whole page

Comment: In that case use `$("#your_div").children().bind('click', function(){ return false; });`

Comment: Do I need to import any libraries to make this work ? [I only import jQuery at the moment]

Answer (score 1):

Guess this would help you:

```
function disableClick(){
    if(window.event.target.id && window.event.target.id=="myDiv"){
        window.event.preventDefault();
    }
}


    document.onclick = disableClick;
    document.oncontextmenu = disableClick;
```

Comment: You can add one more handler with the same function. but for document.onlick

Comment: Ok, this should work, but it doesn't ... if added this to my body of the page then to the head... still don't work... what am I doing wrong ?

What I have added:
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableClick(){
    if(window.event.target.id && window.event.target.id=="counter"){
        window.event.preventDefault();
    }
}


    document.onclick = disableClick;
    document.oncontextmenu = disableClick;
</script>

Comment: maybe it doesn't work cause the link itself lives in an iFrame and its probably created through java script in the first place... what do you think ?

Comment: Is it possible to see the part of html and js relevant to the 'counter'?